# Laravel where has passing additional arguments to function

Tags: php, laravel, arguments, closures

The following obviously results in undefined variable.

```
public function show($locale, $slug)
{
 $article = Article::whereHas('translations', function ($query) {
 $query->where('locale', 'en')
  ->where('slug', $slug);
 })->first();

   return $article;
}
```

Trying to supply the function with the $slug variable:

```
public function show($locale, $slug)
{
    $article = Article::whereHas('translations', function ($query, $slug) {
        $query->where('locale', 'en')
        ->where('slug', $slug);
    })->first();

    return $article;
}
```

results in

```
Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}()
```

how can you allow the funtion to have access to $slug?
Now this is probably something simple but I cant find what i need to search for.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You have to use `use` to pass variables (in your case, `$slug`) into the closure (this is called [*variable inheriting*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)):

```
public function show($locale, $slug)
{
      $article = Article::whereHas('translations', function ($query) use ($slug) {
        $query->where('locale', 'en') //                             ^^^ HERE
              ->where('slug', $slug);
    })->first();

    return $article;
}
```

If you, in the future, want to pass `$locale` in along with it, just comma-separate it:

```
Article::whereHas('translations', function ($query) use ($slug, $locale) { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Thank you

Comment: Hey @rdiz, how to pass multiple arguments using `when()`  or we have to write `when()` 2 times for both arguments in laravel?

Answer (score 4):

You need to inherit variable from parent scope:

```
public function show($locale, $slug) {

    $article = Article::whereHas('translations', function ($query, $slug) use ($slug){
        $query->where('locale', 'en')
        ->where('slug', $slug);
    })->first();

    return $article;
}
```

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the use language construct.

From here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php